# How to create a loop with fractal noise in AE , (offset turbulence )?

Tags: after-effects, noise

I'm trying to create a loop for footage (fog), however could only create through loop "evolution options," looked tutorials on the internet, but none teaches how to create a loop using the "offset turbulence", anyone have any idea how create this loop with evolution and offset turbulence?

It is this animation, only in loop, following example:

Notes. I created the effect of fog, just can not create the same in order to create a loop with no breaks when it restarts

Sorry for the bad English, yet I do not speak this language

Comment: I found a way to loop , follow the solution to those who are interested or have the same problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V55hA573yRY#

The solution in this 57:07 - Fog Fractal

Comment: Related: http://video.stackexchange.com/a/15816/6685